# How can I change formatting of date in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I change a date from the form 01/01/02 to January 1st, 2002?

Can I do this in javascript? If not, jQuery?

Answer (score 2):

While you can certainly write your own date formatting routine, your best choice is using a library like moment.js. That is especially true if you'd be doing some manipulations to those dates besides just displaying them. Dates are hard to do and there are many things to consider (i.e. timezones)...

Answer (score 1):

Using momentjs:

```js
var x = moment('01/01/02', 'mm/dd/YYYY').format('MMM Do, YYYY');

console.log(x);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.14.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

[dateObj.toLocaleDateString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString) in javascript might be helpful